# How to save converted JPG image from PDF using Imagemagick to database

Tags: php, imagemagick

**loading pdf file  from php form**

```
                $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
                $fileName = substr($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 5).".".$ext;
                date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
                $fileDate = date('d.m.Y');
                $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
                $folder = $_POST['folder'];


                $target_dir="$media_dir/";
                $target_file= $target_dir .  basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

**Move file from tmp to media path**

```
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_file);
```

**converting pdf to jpg using Imagick**

```
                $imagick = new imagick();
                $imagick->readImage($target_file);
                $imagick->setImageFormat('jpg');

                $image= basename($target_file,".pdf");

                foreach($imagick as $i=>$imagick) 
                { 

                    $imagick->writeImage($target_dir . $image . ($i+1) ." of ".  $pages.".jpg"); 



                } $imagick->clear();
```

How can I save the converted image to a database. Currently, it is just uploading the original pdf image to the database.

```
                $id_object = _addMediaFile($name, $fileName, 2, $fileSize, $folder);



               $ret = array("ID" => $id_object, "name" => $name, "fileName" => $fileName, "fileSize" => $fileSize, "fileDate" => $fileDate, "fileType" => 4, "folder" => $folder);
                echo json_encode($ret);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider converting the image directly into a blob that you directly save into a database column of blob type. For instance, with `$a = $image->getImageBlob();` you would save `$a` into the database. Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimageblob.php

Comment: Thank you very much for this wonderful help. does that mean i shouldnt convert the pdf image to jpg using getImageBlob()  in that for loop or just right after converting image to jpg using writeimage i should use getImageBlob() to convert to Blob.would highly appreciate if u could guide me with reference to code above as am new to php... foreach($imagick as $i=>$imagick) { $imagick->writeImage($target_dir . $image . ($i+1) ." of ". $pages.".jpg"); $a=$imagick->getImageBlob();